# Prove that if $n$ is a perfect cube, then $n + 4$ is not a perfect cube, where $n > 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I've tried to write up a proof in many ways but always came up with a dead end. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The difference between two cubes is at least $8-1=7$, except for $1^3-0^3$. So it cannot be $4$.

Comment: For cubes of consecutive numbers,  $(n+1)^3$ and $n^3$ find the difference by subtraction. It will be more than 4.

Answer (score 2):

Every cube $n^3$ is congruent $0,1,-1$ modulo $9$. But $n^3+4$ is congruent $3,4,5$ modulo $9$, hence not a cube.

Comment: How did you choose the modulus ?

Comment: You choose the modulus $n$ in such a way $3\mid \varphi(n)$. So, you try first $n=7$ and $n=9$ (both of them work for this example)..

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually, it comes from Fermat's equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$, and considering modulo $9$ is an idea of Euler.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=k^3$, then $(k+1)^3=k^3+3k^2+3k+1>n+4$.

---

As $k>1$, you even have $(k+1)^3>n+18$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x^3+4=y^3$ for some integer $x<y$. Note $xy\neq 0$.

If they have the same sign then $xy\ge 2$ hence
$$
4=y^3-x^3=(y-x)((y-x)^2+3xy) \ge 1\cdot (1+3\cdot 2)>4,
$$
which is a contradiction. If they have different signs then $x+y \le -3$ and $xy\le -2$ hence similarly
$$
4=y^3-x^3=(y-x)((y+x)^2-xy) \ge 1\cdot (3^2+2)>4.
$$